# Plotly error message Error: Client error: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: charts, plotly, interactive

I've created some nice interactive charts in R Studio using the 'ggplotly' function. I would like to embed these in a PowerPoint presentation; however, when I try and publish a chart to my Plotly account I get the following error message -

*Error: Client error: (413) Request Entity Too Large
This file is too big! Your current subscription is limited to 524.288 KB uploads. For more information, please visit: https://plotly.com/get-pricing/.*

Is there a simple way around this error message? Or perhaps another way in which I can embed interactive charts into Powerpoint?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!